# MongoDb simulate Join between 2 collections

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to simulate a join in MongoDb 3.0?

Problem:

I have 2 collections (A and B). The documents from collection A have a key that references a document in the collection B.

I want to Get all documents in collection B that dont have any referenced document in Collection A.

Comment: I can show you how to do this in the native mongoDB shell but I have a feeling thats not where you need to do it. Are you using a javascript backend?

Comment: I'm using .Net but if you can give me an example I will change the code to work in C#. Btw I'm using Mongo 3.0.

Comment: Which version of Mongo are you using?  3.2 supports a left outer joins via the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation stage.

Comment: I have found $lookup but it's only available at 3.2 :(

Comment: In that case then no, you will have to perform the join in the application.

Comment: There is no way ? MapReduce or Aggregation?

Comment: It's possible to "simulate" in every version, but that "simulation" means the actual "appearence" of a join is actually happening in the "client" rather than the "server". Your question is horribly broad though even if seemingly simplistic. As even asking *"how do I join?"* raises questions about "why?" you are even doing this. NoSQL databases like MongoDB support different structures and embedding for the "express purpose" of avoiding the cost of joins, and your general schema infrastructure if not all, should be instead achitected differently to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the Mongoose driver for NodeJS. It is not that helpful to be able to do this in shell, so here it is in Mongooose:

```
var docsWithoutA = [];
var stream = db.colB.find({}).stream();
stream.on("data", function (doc) {
  colA.find({"_id": doc.referenceKeyHere}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) return;
    if (!docs[0]) { docsWithoutA.push(doc) } //doc here is the doc from B with no find results in A
    //found at least one ref'd doc.
  })
})
stream.on("close", function () {
  console.log(docsWithoutA); //Stream closes, here is your list
})
```

This a temporary join accomplishing your specific request.

The real answer is that you should never do a join using MongoDB, references of this class are best handled by establishing subdocuments. More info: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

EDIT: By the way I am no longer confident in my claim to be able to show you how to do this in the Mongo shell, as I forgot $lookup is now not available in 3.0. Someone else's answer (deleted, I think?) also ran into this problem.